# How to modify Levenshtein algorithm, to know if it inserted, deleted, or substituted a character?

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

So I am trying to devise a spin off of the Levenshtein algorithm, where I keep track of what transformations I did in the string(inserted a, or substitute a for b).

Example:

Basically, say I am computing the edit distance of "bbd" and "bcd"

The edit distance will be 1 and the transformation will be "substitude b for c"

**Question:**
How would I approach this problem since the implementations i've seen do not concern themselves with knowing what kind of operation it was but only the total cost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) module - there is an `editops` function there, which returns a list with the operations needed to transform one string to another.

Example:

```
Levenshtein.editops("FBBDE", "BCDASD")
[('delete', 0, 0), ('replace', 2, 1), ('insert', 4, 3), ('insert', 4, 4), ('replace', 4, 5)]
```

From the docs:

> Find sequence of edit operations transforming one string to another.
>
> editops(source_string, destination_string)
> editops(edit_operations, source_length, destination_length)
>
> The result is a list of triples (operation, spos, dpos), where
> operation is one of 'equal', 'replace', 'insert', or 'delete';  spos
> and dpos are position of characters in the first (source) and the
> second (destination) strings.  These are operations on single
> characters.  In fact the returned list doesn't contain the 'equal',
> but all the related functions accept both lists with and without
> 'equal's.